# How do you INCLUDE subscripts in linker file (.ld file)?

Tags: c++, c, linker

I have successfully included a separate `.ld` file into my main `.ld` file like this

```
INCLUDE memory.ld
```

Now I want to include another `.ld` file within the `SECTIONS` area e.g.

```
SECTIONS
{
    .foo {...}
    .bar {...}
    ...

    INCLUDE dwarf.ld
}
```

The [documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/File-Commands.html) explains this should be possible - I think?

> You can place INCLUDE directives at the top level, in MEMORY or SECTIONS commands, or in output section descriptions.

However, I am getting this error:

```
ld: error: /home/project/link_file.ld:198: malformed number: dwarf.ld
>>>   INCLUDE dwarf.ld
>>>           ^
```

Is it possible to do something like this? Does anyone have any suggestion why this message comes up?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example (without objects if possible)?  There are different modes/states of GNU ld lexing and the function of 'INCLUDE' is different based on the mode/state.  I don't see 'malformed' in the gnu ld source, so it is a lex or bison issue.  I had similar issues, but gave up and just used the C pre-processor.  The benefit is you can share `#define` with C/C++ source for one source of truth.

Comment: Thanks, okay. I was hoping for an obvious answer and dont want to spend too long fiddling with this if that is the case... For now I have wrapped the contents of `dwarf.ld` in its own `SECTION` and do the `INCLUDE dwarf.ld` after the main `SECTION` finishes. The pre-processor is a good shout. I am looking into it and hopefully move on with that soon.